# How do I encode bv-redand using the z3 Python API?

Tags: python, z3

Suppose I wish to encode something like the following expression using the Z3 python API:

```
(bv-redand
    (bv-or
        (bv-xnor symbolic_bit_0 
            (bv-concat src_ip dst_ip src_port dst_port))
        symbolic_dc_0)))))
```

How would I do this?

It appears I must do something like:

```
And(~(symbolic_bit_0 ^ Concat(src_ip dst_ip src_port dst_port)) | symbolic_dc_0)
```

But the outermost And doesn't seem to work. One hack I can think of is to avoid the And and instead compare with all 1s, but is there a better way of doing this?

As a side note, is there a way to directly specify a Xnor b instead of ~(a ^ b)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduction-And, Reduction-Or were not added to the Python API yet. Note that Reduction-And is quite different from 'normal and'. I have now added those to the unstable branch. For reference and future use, we can add functions that exist in the C-API but not in the Python API from the outside as well. For instance, in this case we can define

```
def BVRedAnd(a):
    return BitVecRef(Z3_mk_bvredand(a.ctx_ref(), a.as_ast()), a.ctx)
```

The other Boolean operators have Python equivalents, but XNor doesn't. So, the corresponding function has not been added. However, we can again define one if we want to:

```
def BVXNor(a, b):
    return BitVecRef(Z3_mk_bvxnor(a.ctx_ref(), a.as_ast(), b.as_ast()), a.ctx)
```

The difference in performance will however be negligible.

Comment: Thank you Christoph. This was very helpful.